# Hibernate Lazy Loading HQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, lazy-loading

Hibernate + HibernateTemplate + Lazy Loading + HQL

We are using HibernateTemplate's find method by passing a HQL query. How do i retrieve the child elements as we have configured Lazy Loading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. You can get the elements of the collection by using `JOIN FETCH` in the HQL query, or you can later call `Hibernate.initialize(entity.getSomeLazyCollection())`